# Waiving of access checking rules for explicit function template specializations in C++20

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20, compiler-bug

[[temp.spec]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.spec#6) was added to C++20 by implementation of [P0692R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0692r1.html) (*Access Checking on Specialization*) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[temp.spec]/6** The usual access checking rules **do not apply to names in a declaration of** an explicit instantiation or **explicit specialization**, with the exception of names appearing in a function body, default argument, base-clause, member-specification, enumerator-list, or static data member or variable template initializer. [ Note: In particular, **the template arguments** and names **used in the function declarator** (including parameter types, return types and exception specifications) **may be private types** or objects that would normally not be accessible. — end note ]

which, afaict, would make the following program well-formed as of C++20:

```
class A { class B {}; };

template<typename T> void foo() {};
template<> void foo<A::B>() {}

int main() {}
```

However, both GCC (*HEAD 11.0.0 20201121;* [DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dxk0zSgJqziidn2E)) and Clang (*HEAD 12.0.0;* [DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dxk0zSgJqziidn2E)) rejects the program above (for `-std=c++20`/`-std=c++2a`), citing an private access violation

> GCC:
>
> ```
> 'class A::B' is private within this context
> ```
>
> Clang:
>
> ```
> error: 'B' is a private member of 'A'
> ```

GCC lists P0692R1 as implemented:

- [GCC: C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

whereas Clang lists its implementation of P0692R1 as *Partial*:

- [C++ Support in Clang: C++20 implementation status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

#### Question

- What is the correct behaviour in C++20 here, is the program above well-formed (GCC bug / Clang not fully implemented) or are GCC and Clang correct to reject it?

Comment: I don't see anything in your quote that suggests that this rule is only for class templates. Both gcc and clang support this for class templates. While function template specialization is highly questionable, neither gcc nor clang support this for variable template specializations either.

Comment: @Barry Thanks, I agree with that interpretation. I will file bug reports and update this question with an answer linking to them.

Comment: [GCC bug report 97942](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97942).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct behaviour in C++20 here, is the program above well-formed (GCC bug / Clang not fully implemented) or are GCC and Clang correct to reject it?

As already cited in the OP, [temp.spec]/6 supports this feature, and the program is well-formed. Particularly, all of snippets (A) through (D) below are well-formed:

```
// (A)
class A { class B {}; };
 
template<typename T> struct S {};
template<> struct S<A::B> {};

// (B)
class A { class B {}; };
 
template<typename T> void foo() {};
template<> void foo<A::B>() {}
 
// (C)
class A { class B {}; };
 
template<typename T>
constexpr bool v = false;

template<>
constexpr bool v<A::B> = true;

// (D)
class A { class B {}; };

template<typename T, typename U> struct S {};
template<typename U> struct S<A::B, U> {};
template<typename T> struct S<T, A::B> {};
```

GCC is wrong to reject (B) and (C) (correctly accepts (A) and (D)), and Clang is wrong<sup>(1)</sup> to reject (B) through (D) (correctly accepts (A)).

Bug reports:

- GCC (confirmed): [[C++20][P0692R1] Access checking not waived for declarations of explicit specializations of function and variable templates](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97942)
- Clang: [[P0692R1] Access checking not waived for declarations of explicit specializations of function and variable templates](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51769)

<sub>(1) Note that Clang (as highlighted in the OP) has marked the implementation status for P0692R1 as "Partial", so this may not be a Clang bug but rather a feature yet to be implemented C++2a/C++20.</sub>